# Worpress tabular pricing table plugin

Tags: wordpress

I've looked around quite a bit to find a pricing table plugin for the e-commerce website I'm building that matches my requirement below. I haven't been able to find any free or paid plugins.

As described by the picture below, an user must be able to chose any number of plans across different products & be able to check out all of them with a shopping cart at one go

[image]

Please could I request help to understand how to go about implementing this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing you would want to do is creating subscription plans in WooCommerce using a plugin like [YITH WooCommerce Subscription](https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/yith-woocommerce-subscription/).

Once you are done doing that, your users can select individual products with their corresponding subscriptions. To make a tabular format as mentioned above, you will need to copy the template folder from WooCommerce into your theme and edit the `archive-product.php` template to enlist all the products with their corresponding attributes and an add to cart button.

I am not sure if following plugin exactly does what you want, but it does enlist all the products together.
https://barn2.com/wordpress-plugins/woocommerce-product-table/

Comment: Thank you. Although this wasn't the direct answer, it opened up my thinking. Highly appreciate your help